# PHP how to automatically call a custom function after some built-in function is called?

Tags: php, function, function-call

So let's say I need to call my specified function after built-in PHP `date()` function is called, is it possible to do it? Can't find anything about it or I'm not able to properly search for it.

I need to work it like callback, so everytime `date()` function is called my specified function should run after that also and have all those arguments that were provided to `date()` function.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what have you tried thus far?

Comment: You would need function overloading and middleware to achieve this behaviour. PHP does not allow you to overload function which has already been defined and `date()` function does not follow middleware implementation. I would suggest you define your own class instead of using raw `date()` and use middleware to achieve the action trigger.

Comment: You can define custom function `_date()` and in the function call `date()` and then `myFunction()`. So use `_date()` instead of `date()` in your code

Answer (score 1):

You can define alternative function `_date()` that call `date()` and your special function. So you use `_date()` in your code instead of `date()`

```
function _date($format, $timestamp = null){
    $result = !isset($timestamp) ? date($format) : date($format, $timestamp);
    myFunction($format, $timestamp);
    return $result;
}
function myFunction($format, $timestamp){
    echo $format."/";
}
echo _date("Y-m-d");
// output: Y-m-d/2018-11-07
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/4YiHM)